# Drupal 7 node template & views

Tags: drupal, view, nodereference

I have been building websites for a long time and I just started working with Drupal 7. To get a better layout on a content type (node) I use node template. I have a content type Event and a content type DJ. On an Event node I have a DJ linked to it with node reference but I want this to be a block (view). When I create the view I tried everything and all I got are all the DJ's or none. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: I've worked with Views a bunch in my days but I'd need more information, screen shots of the Views edit UI, at least, to give a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use node relationship to get content of the DJ node(s) associated with the event.
I use entity reference module but it should do the same job.